# How can I prevent Zeitgeist from reading clipboard?

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d, zeitgeist

When I copy ID/password to clipboard, only password is copied, because Zeitgeist catches ID from gpass as if I were pressing Ctrl V. Is it possible to avoid? Activity Log Manager seems to not help in this case. Activity logging is stopped, but clipboard is read anyway.

Comment: BTW, this happens only with unity-2d.

Comment: Nothing to do with Zeitgeist

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the Feedback. Zeitgeist does not have anything to do with the clipboard. It can't be Zeitgeist

Comment: Can you re-word question (excluding Zeitgeist)?

Comment: @david6 Zeitgeist has nothing to do with clipboard (as of now: 11th  Feb 2012)